# Forward and Backward Projections

Tags: fourier-analysis, linear-transformations, transformation, projection

I have the transform functions (forward and backward projections) such as:

$$FP\{f(x,y)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(r\cos(\theta) - z\sin(\theta), r\sin(\theta) + z\cos(\theta))dz$$
$$BP\{g_{\theta}(r)\} = \int_{0}^{\pi}g_{\theta}(x\cos(\theta) + y\sin(\theta))d\theta$$

What i want to solve is that first forward projection, which is: $FP\{\delta(x,y)\} = ?$, then i want to solve the backward projection of the result, which actually is: $BP\{FP\{\delta(x,y)\}\}=?$.

I know that the answers must be $BP\{FP\{\delta(x,y)\}\}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$.

This problem occurs during study of the Radon transform.

Comment: I didn't like that you cross-posted here and then deleted your question including my answer over at DSP.SE without any warning :(

Answer (score 0):

Let's –boringly– just insert the functional in question and see where it takes us:

$$\newcommand{\FP}[1]{\mathrm{FP}\{#1\}(r,\theta)}
$$

\begin{align}
\FP{\delta(x,y)} &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(r\cos(\theta) - z\sin(\theta), r\sin(\theta) + z\cos(\theta))dz\\
&=\#\left\{z|r\cos(\theta) - z\sin(\theta) = 0 \wedge r\sin(\theta) + z\cos(\theta)=0\right\}\\
&= \#\left\{z|r\cos(\theta) = z\sin(\theta)  \wedge r\sin(\theta) = - z\cos(\theta)\right\}\tag{*}\\[2em]
&\underline{\text{1. case: $\cos\theta\ne0,\,r\ne0,\,n\in\mathbb Z$}}\\
&= \#\left\{z| r= z\tan(\theta)  \wedge r\tan(\theta) = - z\right\}\\
&= \#\left\{z\Big| \frac rz=\tan(\theta)  \wedge \tan(\theta) = - \frac zr\right\}\\
&\text{$\tan\theta$ takes any arbitrary but fixed value $\in\mathbb R$:}\\
&= \#\left\{z\Big| \frac rz = - \frac zr\right\}\\
&= \#\left\{z| r^2 = - z^2\right\}\\
&= 0 \text{ (because $r^2>0\ge-z^2$)}\\[2em]
&\underline{\text{2. case: $r=0$}}\\
(*) &= \#\left\{z| 0 = z\sin(\theta)  \wedge 0 = - z\cos(\theta)\right\}\\
&= \#\left\{z|0 = z\sin(\theta)  \wedge 0 = z\cos(\theta)\right\}\\
&=1 \text{ (namely, $z=0$, since $\sin\theta\ne\cos\theta$)}\\[2em]
&\underline{\text{3. case: $\cos\theta=0,\,r\ne0,\,n\in\mathbb Z$}}\\
(*) &= \#\left\{z| r0 = z1  \wedge r1 = - z0\right\}\\
 &= \#\left\{z|z=0  \wedge r = 0\right\}\\
&= 0
\end{align}

Thus, in total:

$$\FP{\delta}(r,\theta) = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{when} &r=0 \\
0 &\text{else.}
\end{cases}$$